# "Drush up" runs updates automatically

Tags: drupal, drush

In a Drupal site, I ran "Drush up" to upgrade some modules though I didn't want to upgrade all so I chose to back out of it. However, Drush still ran the databases updates automatically. Is this usual behavior?

When it came to `Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n):` "y" was filled in by Drush. How can this be disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update code only is  [`drush pm-updatecode`](http://drush.ws/help/5#pm-updatecode) or `pm upc` for short.

`drush up` = Update Drupal core and contrib projects and apply any pending database updates (Same as pm-updatecode + updatedb).